# I've got no idea how to write C-code about pyramid

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I made this by an helper and I tried to unify the location of the sum of each row, but I don't know how to fix it. I think the part of printf("%2d", j) from inner for should be changed, but I have no idea for this.

```
for (i = 1; i <= s; i++)

{
    sumOfRow = 0;

    for (j = i; j <= s; j++)

    {
        printf("%2d", j);

        sumOfRow += j;
    }

    printf("\t\t%-5d\n", sumOfRow);

    sum += sumOfRow;

}
printf("Sum of all numbers is %d\n", sum);

getchar();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int s, i, j, sum = 0;

    // create new variable to store sum of single row
    int row_sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the size:");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    for (i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0; // reset sum for each row
        for (j = i; j <= s; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", j);
            row_sum += j; // add current number to row_sum
        }
        printf("\t%d\n", row_sum);
        sum += row_sum; // add current row_sum to total sum
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

#### EDIT

To add padding, you can use the following trick -

```c
printf("%*s", paddingLength, "");
```

This will print an empty string that will take "paddingLength" characters.

For each value in a row, we have 3 chars, 2 for the value and one for space. So, add a padding of `3*i` before printing `row_sum`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int s, i, j, sum = 0;

    int row_sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the size:");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    for (i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0;
        for (j = i; j <= s; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", j); // this will have fixed length of 3
            row_sum += j;
        }
        printf("\%*s%d\n", 3*i , "", row_sum); // print 3*i whitespace before row_sum
        sum += row_sum;
    }
    printf("%*s%d\n", 3*i, "", sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
Enter the size:6
 1  2  3  4  5  6    21
 2  3  4  5  6       20
 3  4  5  6          18
 4  5  6             15
 5  6                11
 6                   6
                     91
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. Thanks to you, I am learning many things.

Comment: Actually, the row_sum and total sum can also be found directly without calculating it by going over each value in the row.

Comment: Okay, I got it and thank you for your advise!

Comment: actually when I tried to start this code, the location of the sum of each row has changed every 3 lines. If you don't mind, do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int s, i, j, ttl=0;
    
    printf("Enter the size:");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    int sum[s];
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        sum[i]=0;
        for (j = i; j < s; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d", j);
            sum[i] += j;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int k=0; k< s;k++){
        printf(" sum of %d is: %d ", k, sum[k]);
        ttl += sum[k];
    }
     printf(" total sum is: %d" , ttl);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god. I express my deep gratitude for your hard work. Thank you so much. I'll try to that way.

Comment: hope it helped you ,edited set value of array to default 0 causing garbage value now this will work flawlessly . ping me anytime for any query

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf. What about some newlines in the printfs?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the size: " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        if ( !( n < N ) ) n = N - 1;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        const int WIDTH = 25;
        unsigned int sum = 0;
        
        for ( unsigned int  i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int partial_sum = 0;
            
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < n - i; j++ )
            {
                unsigned int value = i + j + 1;
                printf( "%u ", value );
                partial_sum += value;
            }
            
            printf( "%*u\n", WIDTH  - 2 * n + 2 * i, partial_sum );

            sum += partial_sum;
        }
        
        printf( "Total of the numbers = %u\n\n", sum );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the size: 6

1 2 3 4 5 6            21
2 3 4 5 6              20
3 4 5 6                18
4 5 6                  15
5 6                    11
6                       6
Total of the numbers = 91

Enter the size: 7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7          28
2 3 4 5 6 7            27
3 4 5 6 7              25
4 5 6 7                22
5 6 7                  18
6 7                    13
7                       7
Total of the numbers = 140

Enter the size: 8

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8        36
2 3 4 5 6 7 8          35
3 4 5 6 7 8            33
4 5 6 7 8              30
5 6 7 8                26
6 7 8                  21
7 8                    15
8                       8
Total of the numbers = 204

Enter the size: 9

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9      45
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9        44
3 4 5 6 7 8 9          42
4 5 6 7 8 9            39
5 6 7 8 9              35
6 7 8 9                30
7 8 9                  24
8 9                    17
9                       9
Total of the numbers = 285

Enter the size: 0
```